# jqGrid - beforeProcessing not Firing in 4.6.0

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use beforeProcessing to change the data before it renders in the grid, but that function is skipped every time. I am using jqGrid 4.6.0, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code where I set everything up. Let me know if you need more detail. Any help would be great!

```
        $gridTable.jqGrid({
            data: fixData(),
            datatype: "local",
            colNames:columnNames,
            colModel:columnModel,
            autowidth : true,
            multiSort: true,
            sortname: sortName,
            sortorder: sortOrder,
            viewrecords: false,
            rowNum: 20000,
            rowList: [],        // disable page size dropdown
            pgbuttons: false,   // disable page control like next, back button
            pgtext: null,
            onSortCol: onSort,
            gridComplete: onGridComplete,
            beforeProcessing: function () {
              console.log("blah");
            },
            shrinkToFit:false
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal of `beforeProcessing` is to provide a possibility to modify data returned asynchronously via Ajax from the server. In case of loading the data from the server one have no data at the moment of creating of the grid and at the next line of JavaScript code after the grid is created. The data will be returned from the server at unknown moment later. Especially for the case `beforeProcessing` is introduced. jqGrid makes `$.ajax` call and it calls `beforeProcessing` callback inside of `success` callback of `$.ajax` directly at the beginning. The `beforeProcessing` callback allows to modify the data or skip processing of the server response (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2013-L2019) of jqGrid code).

Your code use `datatype: "local"` and all input data you provide using `data` options. In the case there are no problem at all. If you need modify the input data you an do it directly.

```
var mydata = fixData();

// now one can make any modifications of mydata.

// now one can create jqGrid using modified mydata as the input data.
$gridTable.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    ...
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true
});
```

I included in the above code two options `gridview: true`, which improves the performance of the filling of the grid, and `autoencode: true` which force jqGrid to interpret the input data as pure data and not as HTML fragments. In the case the special HTML charachters like `&`, `<`, `>` etc which cab be inside of input data will be always displayed correctly.

Some other options (`viewrecords: false`, `rowList: []`, `pgbuttons: false`, `pgtext: null`) I would recommend you to remove because there have mo meaning if you don't use `pager` or `toppager` parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will change the options. I understand what you are saying about beginProcessing - I was hoping that I could use that even to review data after a sort and before the grid is rendered.